How to ensure highest priority for custom Window Tiling keyboard shortcuts across all applications?
I am attempting to make the switch from using Rectangle to using MacOS Sequoia's new built-in Window Tiling. I attempted to change all of Apple's default keyboard shortcuts to match my muscle memory:

Safari ignores my Fill (CTRL+OPT+UP) command on any webpage large enough to be scrolled. Can anyone suggest a way to make my keyboard shortcuts take priority across ALL applications?
